How to create 30-second video fragments in real-time while recording screen using MediaRecorder in Android?
I am developing an Android application where I need to record the screen and, during the recording process, generate 30-second video fragments in real-time to be uploaded to a server using an API.
Here's what I have achieved so far:

I can successfully record the screen using MediaRecorder.
I can create 30-second video fragments after the recording has finished.
I can upload the fragments to the server.

However, I'm facing an issue when trying to create these 30-second fragments during the recording. When I attempt to open the video file that is currently being recorded, I encounter an error because the file has not been closed yet. This prevents me from generating video fragments in real-time.
How can I achieve the generation of 30-second video fragments in real-time while the recording is still ongoing? Are there any specific techniques or libraries I should use to accomplish this?
I have tried the following approaches:

Splitting the video after recording: I successfully implemented a method to split the recorded video into 30-second fragments after the recording has finished. This works, but does not meet the requirement of generating the fragments in real-time.

Accessing the file during recording: I attempted to open the video file that is actively being recorded by MediaRecorder to create fragments. However, this resulted in an error because the file is not closed and therefore not accessible for reading.

Using separate MediaRecorder instances: I tried to use multiple MediaRecorder instances to start a new recording every 30 seconds. This approach was cumbersome and resulted in overlaps and synchronization issues.


I expected to find a way to either:

Access and read the video data being recorded in real-time without needing to close the file.
Implement a method to generate 30-second video fragments seamlessly during the ongoing recording.

Any insights or alternative methods to achieve real-time video fragment generation while recording would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Maybe you need to forget MediaRecorder and look at some of Android's camera libraries or some computer vision library like OpenCV for more control over the saving procedure(?)

@MarkusKauppinen Is that factibe? can I use openCV instead of MediaRecorder? Do you know if there is any documentation or examples somewhere? THX
